# How do I get the 'else' condition to show up?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on an app in Code.org and I can't seem to figure out why my if statement isn't working.

What I want my code to do is to check if what the user guesses as the rank position for the song is correct, then the word 'correct' will show in a textbook below. And if it isn't correct then the word 'wrong' should show. But all it does is show 'wrong'.
sorry for the bad explanation, I don't really know how to explain this.

here is a more updated version of my code:

```
// variables 
var songList =getColumn("Viral 50 USA", "Track Name") ;
var artistList = getColumn("Viral 50 USA", "Artist");
var rankList= getColumn("Viral 50 USA", "Position");

// filtered lists 
var filteredSongList = [];
var filteredArtistList = [];
var filteredRankList= [];

// first function chooses a random song from the data
function randomSongFunction() {
  filteredSongList= [];
  filteredArtistList= [];
  filteredRankList= [];
 for (var i = 0; i < songList.length; i++) {
    var song = songList[i];
    if (song == songList[i]) {
      appendItem(filteredSongList, songList[i]);
      appendItem(filteredArtistList, artistList[i]);
      appendItem(filteredRankList, rankList[i]);
    }
  }
}

// displays the actual text of the song and artists name on screen2 using the filtered lists
function updateScreen2() {
  var index = randomNumber(0, filterSongList.length-1);
  setText("artistOutput", filterArtistList[index]);
  setText("songOutput", filterSongList[index]);
}

// when the start button is clicked the screen changes
onEvent("startButton", "click", function( ) {
  setScreen("screen2");
});
onEvent("yesButton", "click", function( ) {
  setScreen("screen3");
});
onEvent("noButton", "click", function( ) {
  setScreen("screen1");
});
onEvent("homeButton", "click", function( ) {
  setScreen("screen1");
});
// when the button is clicked, it will call the functions
onEvent("chooseButton", "click", function( ) {
  randomSongFunction();
  updateScreen2();
});
// 
onEvent("checkButton", "click", function( ) {
  var guessRankNum = getProperty("dropdown", "value");
  for (var i = 0; i < rankList.length; i++) {
    if (guessRankNum == rankList[i]) {
      setText("answerOutput", "correct!");
    } else {
      setText("answerOutput", "wrong");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program,
`randomSongFunction();` is not being called, so there isn't a rank for `rankFunction();` to compare the dropdown's answer to.

When I put your code in code.org, it wasn't resulting in anything, even though I imported the same list, etc. When I called `randomSongFunction`, it displays "wrong." I'm just not sure if that was working correctly because I did not have the original dropdown options since they weren't specified.

See if calling `randomSongFunction();` before `rankFunction();` works for you.

I hope this helps!